# How can we add attribute to the Person object in the project ? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, web-scraping, attributes

This is a fundamental question, but I can't figure it out for two days.
Please bear with me, I am trying to add more attributes to the person object of this https://github.com/joshuatz/linkedin-to-jsonresume.

My understanding is that we have objects.py where it has Contact, Experience, Education and ... objects class. In person.py, we import  Experience, Education, Scraper, Interest, Accomplishment, Contact.  At the same time, the person is a subclass of Scraper. so we can add more attributes in the **init** of person.
***But*** I can't get it to work since it gets giving me the

```
 "AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'c'" error
```

in person.py,  it has

```
  def __init__(
 17         self,
 18         c=None,
 19         driver=None,
 20         scrape=True,
 21         close_on_complete=True,
 22     ):
 23         self.c = c or []
 24 

 46     def add_c(self, c):
 47         self.c.append(c)




 82 
 83         # get connections
 84         try:
 85             driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/")
 86             _ = WebDriverWait(driver, self.__WAIT_FOR_ELEMENT_TIMEOUT).until(
 87                 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mn-connections"))
 88             )
 89             connections = driver.find_element_by_class_name("mn-connections")
 90             if connections is not None:
 91                 for conn in connections.find_elements_by_class_name("mn-connection-card"):
 92                     anchor = conn.find_element_by_class_name("mn-connection-card__link")



 93                     url = anchor.get_attribute("href")
 94                     name = conn.find_element_by_class_name("mn-connection-card__details").find_element_by_class_name("mn-connection-card__name").text.strip()
 95                     occupation = conn.find_element_by_class_name("mn-connection-card__details").find_element_by_class_name("mn-connection-card__occupation").text.strip()
 96 
 97                     c = Contact(c=name)
 98                     print(a)
 99 
100                     self.add_c(c)
101         except:
102             connections = None
103 
104         if close_on_complete:
105             driver.quit()


   def __repr__(self):
117         return
118     "{n}\n\nA\n{a}\n\nphone\n{phone}\n\nExperience\n{exp}\n\nEducation\n{edu}\n\nInterest\n{int}\n\nAccomplishments\n{acc}\n\nc\n{conn}".format(
119             n=self.n,
120             a=self.a,
121             phone=self.phone,
122             exp=self.experiences,
123             edu=self.educations,
124             int=self.interests,
125             acc=self.accomplishments,
126             conn=self.c,
127         )
```

in object.py it has

```
  8 @dataclass
  9 class Contact:
 10     c: str = None
 11
```

Can someone help me understand and add additional Attributes to the current one?

added:
Here is the code that I am working with:

https://github.com/mobilelifeful/joeyism_linkedin_scraper

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, Thank you for the link, but I can't even get it to work so far,  should I just create a non working repo on GitHub and post it here?

Comment: `c` might also not be a good name as it seems to be already in use: `conn=self.c,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

New `person.py` file for experimental purposes:

```py
class Contact:
    c: str = None # contact has one attribute called c

class Person:
    def __init__(self,
            c=None,
            driver=None,
            scrape=True,
            close_on_complete=True):
        if c == None:
            self.c = [] # use empty list
        else:
            self.c = c # take list from parameters

    def add_c(self, c):
        self.c.append(c) # append single contact to list

c1 = Contact()
c1.c = "Joe"
c2 = Contact()
c2.c = "John"
contact_list = [c1, c2]
p = Person(contact_list)
print(p.c[0].c) # print first contact
print(p.c[1].c) # print second contact
print("Again with other initialization:")
q = Person()
q.add_c(c1)
q.add_c(c2)
print(q.c[0].c) # print first contact
print(q.c[1].c) # print second contact
```

```
$ python3 person.py
Joe
John
Again with other initialization:
Joe
John
$
```

The error `'Person' object has no attribute 'c'` may indicate that you have an indentation problem.

Nevertheless, please try to provide a mre (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Else, we cannot reproduce your error and have to guess.

New `person.py` from github code (reduced, class `Contact` added according to its usage):

```py
class Contact:
    c: str = None # contact has one attribute called c
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.c = name

class Person():

    def __init__(
        self,
        c=None,
        driver=None,
        scrape=True,
        close_on_complete=True,
    ):
        self.c = c or []

    def add_c(self, c):
        self.c.append(c)

        # name = "John Smith"
        # c = Contact(name) # above was the append do not overwrite here
        
        # self.add_c(c) # we do want to call ourselves

c1 = Contact("Joe Black")
p=Person()
p.add_c(c1)
print(p.c[0].c)
```

And running:

```
$ python3 person.py
Joe Black
$
```

Comment: Hello @Frank,  Yes, I am trying to do something like this with this project, but I can't get it to work.  Since I am trying to build features on top of the existing project. but can't get it working. Wonder I don't miss some tricks of the current one.

Comment: @data The missing attribute is a basic error. Please try to reduce your example so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: Yes. it is a very basic error, (and it makes me ashamed to ask for help. )
here is the code that I am working with 
https://github.com/mobilelifeful/joeyism_linkedin_scraper .

Comment: I see the person class at (https://github.com/mobilelifeful/joeyism_linkedin_scraper/blob/main/linkedin_scraper/person.py) but I don't see the problem there.

Comment: @data I now added a reduced version from that github file. Unfortunately, it shows other errors. My reduced version with slight changes works fine. See comments in the code.